# Default taxonomy for Wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm struggling to add a default taxonomy to a custom post type. My cpt is this:

```
add_action('init', 'events_register');
 
function events_register() {
 
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Events', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Event'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
        'new_item' => __('New Event'),
        'view_item' => __('View Event'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Events'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => '',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => ['events_category']
      ); 
 
    register_post_type( 'events' , $args );
}
    register_taxonomy('events_category', ['events'], [
        'label' => __('Categories', 'txtdomain'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'events_category'],
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => __('Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'all_items' => __('All Categories', 'txtdomain'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'view_item' => __('View Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'new_item_name' => __('New Author Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Categories', 'txtdomain'),
            'popular_items' => __('Popular Categories', 'txtdomain'),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate Categories with comma', 'txtdomain'),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from most used Categories', 'txtdomain'),
            'not_found' => __('No Categories found', 'txtdomain'),
        ]
    ]);
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('events_category', 'events');
```

I've seen a few suggestions of how to do this but nothing seems to work for me. I tried this to add the default taxonomy as 'default' for example but doesn't do anything:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_default_category' );
function set_default_category( $post_id ) {

    // Get the terms
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'events_category');

    // Only set default if no terms are set yet
    if (!$terms) {
        // Assign the default category
        $default_term = get_term_by('slug', 'default', 'events_category');
        $taxonomy = 'events_category';
        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $default_term, $taxonomy );
    }
}
```

I assume I'm missing something really obvious here but I can't see it!

Comment: could you try adding `'default_term' => 'something'` to register_taxonomy()?

Comment: also please consider using a framework for handling custom post types, custom taxonomies and such. the Pods framework is very handy: https://pods.io/features/

Comment: As simple as that, it worked, thanks!